# Pin View cursor shape not changing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-edittext

I tried to change the shape of the Pin View cursor using the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute but it doesn't get changed.  I have tested the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute with Edit Text and it works well but it's not working for PinView. is there anything I'm doing wrong or is this a bug.

This is my `PinView xml code`:

```
    <com.chaos.view.PinView
        android:id="@+id/otp_pin"
        style="@style/PinWidget.PinView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/we_sent_otp"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:elevation="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:itemBackground="@color/white"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:itemCount="6"
        app:itemRadius="12dp"
        app:lineColor="@color/white"
        app:lineWidth="1dp"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edittext_cursor"/>
```

`edittext_cursor` drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size
        android:width="5dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

Comment: This would be a documentation bug, I would say. It's poorly phrased, at least, given that it states: "PinView inherits from EditText, which means you can use all the APIs from EditText.". `PinView` actually [draws its own cursor, which is nothing more than a simple line](https://github.com/ChaosLeung/PinView/blob/f6bee4ff9348e081d535a8268e320cefc2560cbf/pinview/src/main/java/com/chaos/view/PinView.java#L494).

Comment: Hahaha Okay @MikeM , then it's a documentation bug :) ... thanks a lot...